# post event on facebook profile with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I'm trying to post an event to my facebook profile with the Graph API and PHP.
I've succesfully created an event but its not posted on my profile but only on my app-page.
The fb-app is the creator of the event, but I want my own profile to be the creator and I want  it to apear on my feed. How can I do this?

```
$token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET');
$ch=curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PROFILE_ID/events');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test event&start_time=2011-07-16T19:20&location=someplace&".$token.""); 
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Couldn't you use the PHP SDK and send the requests FROM the SDK? I got it working some hours ago using the SDK, just fine.

Comment: Thanks the facebook PHP SDK works very good for me!

Answer (score 0):

I use the php sdk...

```
$eventInfo = array(
            'name'         => 'name',
            'description'  => strip_tags('description'),
            'owner'         => 'Owner',
            'location'     => 'Location name and street',
            'city'         => 'city',
            'start_time'   => 'starttime',
            'end_time'     => 'endtime',
            'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
        );
$microFlyerBig = 'http://www.example.com/www/img/img.jpg';
$eventInfo[basename($microFlyerBig)] = "@" . realpath($microFlyerBig);
$fbEventId = $facebook->api("/me/events", "post", $eventInfo);
$fbEventId = $fbEventId['id'];
```